# Fetch specific records from mysql based on another columns

Tags: mysql

My database is has 2 columns p & f both are integer type;

Table has following entries

```
p   f
1   5
1   6
2   5
3   6
4   5
4   6
```

I want fetch the records with p where f is 5 & f is 6

So actually I want output as

```
p
1
4
```

when I try it with

```
select p from temp where f=5 or f=6
```

it given me output with all p.

Answer (score 1):

Group by `p` and take only those groups having both `f`:

```
select p 
from temp 
where f in (5,6)
group by p
having count(f) = 2
```

With `having count(f) = 2`, you get only groups having not just one of the `f`s you are looking for but both. If you check for 3 `f`s the query would be `select p from temp where f in (5,6,7) group by p having count(f) = 3`.

Comment: could you explain me the meaning of "having count(f)=2"?

Comment: With `having count(f) = 2` you get only groups having not just one of the `f`s you are looking for but both. If you check for 3 `f`s the query would be `select p 
from temp 
where f in (5,6,7)
group by p
having count(f) = 3`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need `DISTINCT`

```
 SELECT DISTINCT p 
 FROM temp 
 WHERE f=5 or f=6
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
select p from temp where f in (5, 6);
```

hope this helps